# Liquibase exception on Kylo start

Tags: kylo

I created a rpm from master branch and installed it on my HDP 2.4 sandbox  with mysql default metastore for Kylo. I am running into below issue after starting kylo service .  Did anyone encounter this before ?

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:com/thinkbiganalytics/db/changelog/0.0.0/2017-03-24-1135-automated-export.xml::1490096811017-68::ru186002 (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX NN_EXEC_PARAMS_STRING_VAL ON kylo.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(KEY_NAME, STRING_VAL)]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that Kylo requires a newer version of MySQL server.

You can try doing a manual database upgrade and modifying the SQL script to use a shorter key:
http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/DatabaseUpgrades.html